# How to vertically align multiple  images in middle inside div 

Tags: jquery, css, banner, sliders

I am using jQuery.carouFredSel to show banners, so far it works fine except one issue i have banners of variable heights  and banner in this slider always come at top if banner is smaller than other banner then i need to align it in middle middle. How can i do that

I have setup an example on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kzhfe/12/

carouFredSel [link](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/)

I would appreciate help in this regarding. I tried several things but non of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for JS here, just change `display: block; float: left;` to `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle`: http://jsfiddle.net/kzhfe/17/

Comment: I will mark you answer as it is a pure CSS solution, I also appreciate Shih-En as he also gave a working solution.

Comment: Just a note: this solution doesn't work, as the child elements in a carouFredSel need to float: left; If you look at that jsfiddle again, you'll see a banner sitting down below the others, which breaks the carousel functionality. Marking this answer down.

Comment: Yea well his original fiddle also does that. And `float: left` doesn't solve it. With `inline-block` you could just do `white-space: nowrap` though (http://jsfiddle.net/kzhfe/89/) but this is a different problem than the one I answered above and I think the real solution is to simply widen the container div so that it fits all images.

Answer (score 2):

I add code in your example code

Here is the result : http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/kzhfe/16/

```
var h = $("#BannerSlider").height();
        $.map($("#BannerSlider img"), function(e){
            var top =( h- $(e).height())/2;
            $(e).css("margin-top",top);
 });
```

Comment: I think you need vertical align in middle

Comment: I just applied this answer to a caroufredsel on a site I'm working on, and it works perfectly when it's in a $(window).load() with the caroufredsel function call (allowing images to load in to make adjustments) while maintaining the carousel functionality. This should be the correct answer.